# How to implement this TCP stream reader in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, tcp, streaming, spring-integration

I would like a Spring Integration implementation of a stream reader. Another application (outside of java) sends streams of data (delimited by dollar-signs) to port 9999. This server *listens*.

First I made sure the stream was streaming by connecting to it with `telnet 127.0.0.1 9999`.

Then I created a simple java application with the following method. This is working currently.

```
public void readStream() throws IOException{
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        skt.getInputStream()));
        s = new Scanner(bufferedReader);
        s.useDelimiter("[$]");
        System.out.println(s);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.println(s.next());
        }
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to implement this in Spring Integration framework.
I looked at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server and http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration/2.0.0.M3/spring-integration-reference/html/stream.html. However I get confused where to start?
What is needed to connect to the sending application?
(I'm really new to the Spring Framework.)

The difficulty for me lies in the terminology. Should I create a TCP Inbound gateway? or a receiving channel adapter? or is it outbound because I'm requesting the stream??

**EDIT** after comments of Gary:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer" id="deserializer1">
    <constructor-arg type="byte" value="$"/>
</bean>
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server" type="server" port="9999"
    deserializer="deserializer1"
/>
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="adapter" connection-factory="server" request-channel="channel1"/>
<int:channel id="channel1" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inbound gateway is used when the server sends a reply to an inbound request. An inbound channel adapter `(<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter)` is for one-way integration only - the client sends data only and does not receive replies.

You would need a [server connection factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories), configured to use a `ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer` configured with your `$` delimiter, in the `deserializer` property.

Please use the [latest documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) not the old version that was in your question.

Comment: is 'the server' _my_ application, or the _other_ application that sends the data stream?

Comment: The server is your application.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I added some code; is this what you mean?

Comment: For inbound only, you need a channel adapter, not a gateway; you need to set the `deserializer` to decode on the inbound side, to the `serializer` which is for outbound data; you need some subscribed to `channel1` to handle the message.

Comment: Gary, I can't get it to work. I have a TCP server, sending data to 9999 (this is outside the whole java application). My java application should pick up this TCP messages, but it doesn't. I had a look at integration examples such as the echoservice and the rabbitMQ, but I have the feeling I'm still missing something. Shouldn't the factory be a "client" type?

Comment: You said "Another application sends streams of data (delimited by dollar-signs) __to port 9999__", but then I see your java "client" connects __to 9999__ so I am confused. If you want to connect to some other server and then receive data from it, you need `client-mode="true"` on the adapter and, yes, a client factory. Perhaps you could edit your question with a clearer explanation of your use case.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of sockets is not sufficient. In my understanding the server and client meet on one single port number (9999). The external application that streams the data, is configured to serve at 9999. The client (my java application) is configured to listen to 9999. Which part of my question is incorrect in your opinion? And do you agree that type should be **client** as well?

Comment: So, yes, your terminology is incorrect, the __server listens__ on 9999, the __client connects__ to 9999 (not listen). It is quite unusual for a client to connect and then just receive data, but it is possible. To do that with Spring Integration, you need a __client__ connection factory and __client-mode="true"__ on the adapter (normally, an inbound adapter uses a server factory and listens for incoming connections from clients).